# XML Shredding SQL Server performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

How would I parse the below without the XML Namespaces?

I am having a timeout issue due to SQL Server 2008 R2 and I was going to utilize the query hint `OPTION ( OPTIMIZE FOR ( @xml = NULL ) )` but would prefer not to.

If you need more clarification on the query let me know.  Thanks for any assistance.

```
DECLARE @i BIGINT , @rawxml XML

SELECT TOP 1 
    @i = prl.ID,
    @rawxml = prl.d
FROM
    s.dbo.l prl
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM dbo.p
               WHERE id = prl.ID)
ORDER BY 
    prl.ID

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://xxx.xsd' AS pd)
INSERT INTO P (x, y)
    SELECT 
        rn = NULLIF(X.ps.value('(./@rn)[1]', 'varchar(25)'), '')
    FROM 
        @rawxml.nodes('/pd:ps/pd:p') AS X(ps)
```

Comment: Please provide your XML structure...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `*`

```
INSERT INTO dbo.p /*(...)*/
SELECT l.ID, NULLIF(t.c.value('@rn', 'VARCHAR(25)'), '')
FROM dbo.l l
CROSS APPLY d.nodes('/*:ps/*:p') t(c)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.p p
        WHERE p.ID = l.ID
    )
```